# Настройка чпу на сайте

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь настроить чпу на сайте (первый раз), для этого создал файл `.htaccess` в корне. 
С помощью команды

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*uslugi/(.*)$ ?view=uslugi
```

пытаюсь изменить адрес с `test.ru/?view=uslugi` на `test.ru/uslugi`, но команда не работает( Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: впишите имя скрипта `index.php?view=uslugi` и добавьте флаги `[L,NC]`. если вас не интересуют входящие ссылки вида `/vsyakie/ranzye/uslugi/` то уберите из шаблона первые `.*`. а во втором случае скобки их не нужны, если результат не используете все равно

Comment: @teran, если я вас правильно понял, написал так `RewriteRule ^uslugi/.*$ index.php?view=uslugi`, но не работает(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?view=$1 [L]`

Comment: Выдает 500 ую ошибку. 'Internal Server Error'

Comment: @r.mcreal, должно все работать.

Answer (score 0):

Правило

```
RewriteRule ^uslugi($|/) index.php?view=uslugi [L]
```

соответствует ссылкам

```
site.ru/uslugi
site.ru/uslugi/
site.ru/uslugi/test
```

и так далее, все подобные запросы будут перенаправлены в `index.php` а параметр `view` будет равен `uslugi`, после чего обработка правил будет завершена, о чем говорит флаг `[L]`

Comment: Ничего не меняется, почему-то

Comment: Может я что-то пропустил? Может какие-то настройки нужны?